# How to Change a Custom HTML Attribute by Screen Width using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the data-smooth-scroll-offset attribute value for the following div if the screen width is larger than 959px:

This div:

```
<div id="Table-Of-Contents" data-smooth-scroll="1" data-smooth-scroll-offset="20"></div>
```

The JS:

```
function adjustWidth(){

    var actual_width = window.innerWidth;

    if(actual_width > 959) {
        document.getElementById("Table-Of-Contents").data-smooth-scroll-offset="111";
    }
}
```

It appears that data-smooth-scroll-offset is a custom html attribute. Any ideas how to change its value?

Answer (score -1):

You need use event resize for window. When window size changed we get window size and by condition set attr value.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("Table-Of-Contents")
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  if (width > 959) element.setAttribute("data-smooth-scroll-offset","20")
})
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions. Instead, vote to close as duplicate.